# the relationship between machine and assembly language

Tags: assembly, machine-code

What's the relationship between machine language and assembly language programming?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466790/assembly-code-vs-machine-code-vs-object-code

Answer (score 4):

Assembly language was invented to make it easier for humans to write machine language.

Assembly language:

```
MOV AX,1
```

Machine language:

```
B8 01 00    ; B8 = copy two bytes into AX   0001 = value to copy
```

Notice that the assembly language hides turning `0100` into `0001` - this processor is "little endian"

An important difference is that Assembly language offers **labels**:

```
JMP next_thing
```

Machine language:

```
EB FC         ; EB = jump, FC = current address - 4 bytes
```

Before assembly, you had to calculate the jump offset by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Both are implementation-specific and deal with the individual instructions to the processor, but machine-code is slightly lower level, represented to the human programmer as a series of numbers, and almost always in pure binary.

Assembly, on the other hand, is written symbolically, not in pure binary. It is designed to be read by the human programmer and then converted to machine code binary, but still works with individual instructions.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) sums it up well:

> A much more readable rendition of machine language, called assembly language, uses mnemonic codes to refer to machine code instructions, rather than simply using the instructions' numeric values. For example, on the Zilog Z80 processor, the machine code 00000101, which causes the CPU to decrement the B processor register, would be represented in assembly language as DEC B.

Answer (score 0):

Assembly language is a human-readable representation for machine language.