# What is the issue with this code?

Tags: c

I don't understand what is wrong with this C code. I am just asking this for learning purposes. I know the game is kind of stupid but it's just for fun and learning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int response
    char name [20];
        printf ("Welcome to Game1\n");
        printf ("What's your name?\n");
        scanf ("%s",name);
        printf ("From now on you're Private %s\n",name);
        printf ("Loading...\n");
        delay(4000);
        printf("You are in a army excersize yard.\n");
        delay(4000);
        printf("Your sargeant approaches.\n");
        printf ("Sargeant Sam: Drop and give me twenty, Private %s\n",name);
        printf ("1) Yessir!\n2)Make me\n");
        scanf ("%d\n", response);
            if(response==1){
                printf ("You do 20 pushups\n");
            }
            if(response==2){
            printf("Sargeant Sam: What did you say?!\n");
            }
return (0);
}
```

These are the errors

```
game1.c: In function ‘main’:
game1.c:4: error: nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable
game1.c:4: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘char’
game1.c:16: error: ‘response’ undeclared (first use in this function)
game1.c:16: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
game1.c:16: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

I am a complete beginner so please explain everything simply.

Comment: Please stop it man, please put some efforts to learn before repeatedly post same question. for example you have just posted a [question-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793445/what-does-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-mean-in-c) before that [qestion-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792702/when-compiling-a-c-program-i-get-this-error-hello-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 4):

```
int main(){
 int response
             ^
```

missing semicolon here.

Answer (score 3):

```
    int response
```

A declaration ends with a semicolon: `;`.

Besides, there is a lack of coherent [indentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) and `delay` doesn't belong to C standard (not declared in `<stdio.h>`).

Comment: Other post beat you by 15 seconds

Comment: sorry that was a terrible post:( sorry for wasting your time. i cant post anything now because my score is low. now i have a good question that i already researched a lot so please make this higher.