# Why do I need to include .o files when compiling?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

When I compiled my program and ran it, I got a a symbol lookup error. I was doing this:

```
$ gcc -o parts parts.c -lnettle
$ ./parts
$ ./parts: symbol lookup error: ./parts: undefined symbol: nettle_pbkdf2
```

My code included these header files:

```
#include <nettle/pbkdf2.h>
#include <nettle/hmac.h>
#include <pbkdf2-hmac-sha1.c>
```

I solved my problem by including the object files for the two included header files during gcc compilation.

```
$ gcc -o parts parts.c hmac.o pbkdf2.o -lnettle
```

The thing is, I don't understand what is going on and therefore why this works. Why must I include the .o files and not just the header files to avoid symbol lookup or undefined reference errors?

Comment: The headers tell you *what* is defined. The object files provide the actual definition.

Comment: What do you put in your source files, that you think is so unnecessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tobias mentioned, a header file tells the compiler what is done, the object file tells the compiler how it is done.  You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718299/whats-an-object-file-in-c) what an object file *is*, but in reality it's just a precompiled version of a source file.

Truly, you were not actually getting compiler errors, but linker errors. It knew how to compile your source file, but it couldn't put everything together until it got the other object files.

Comment: Thanks. I did some more reading on the whole linker process and it's becoming clearer.