# How to call a C program inside bash script and store its return value to a variable?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I have bash script where I ask the user for some inputs, and then I want to call a C program a few times, and sum the return value. Please note that the main function inside my C program has some `printf` statements also, and it returns an integer value. Here is the part of my bash script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

encBER=0

// Some other code where I read the values from the user

for i in $frames;
do
    tempEncBER=$(./enc_ber $bytes $snr $modulation $channel $alamouti)
    encBER=$((encBER + tempEncBER))
done

echo "Total BER is:" $encBER
```

The point is that I ask it to execute 10 times, meaning the `frames` variables has the value of 10, but it executes once, it shows some syntax error, and then executes again, and for the final result, the value of `encBER` is 0. It simply doesn't store anything there. How can I get the value of the return statement in my main function in my C program and use it in bash?

Comment: The fact that `enc_ber` is a C program is not relevant at all.

Comment: When you say "return value" about the C program, do you mean what is returned using `return` at the end of `main()`? Because what you're doing is storing *the standard output* emitted by the program, which is something completely different.

Comment: Where do you set value of `$frames` with which value?

Comment: If `frame` has the value `10` then `for i in $frames` will loop exactly once with `$i` having the value `10`.

Comment: @unwind Yes, that's exactly what I mean. `return` at the end of `main()`

Comment: Be ware, that although `main()` returns `int` the OS only returns the lowest byte vlaue of the `int` returned by `main()`. So `return 257;` from `int main()` whould end up in the shell with `1`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a BASH variable equal to the output from a command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-bash-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value of a program is store in the `$?` variable. So you only need to add each `$?`:

```
for i in $frames;
do
    ./enc_ber $bytes $snr $modulation $channel $alamouti
    encBER=$((encBER + $?))
done
```

Note that the value is restricted to eight bits, so the maximum value is 255.

---

If you want to capture an integer greater than 255 or a float for instance, use stderr for all the things you don't want (`fprintf(stderr, "Things I don't want\n");`) and stdout to print the return value you want to catch.

Comment: This works. But is there any way to work around the 255 restriction?

Comment: The only way I see is use what you have done, but print to stderr what you don't want and to stdout what you want to capture.

Answer (score 5):

The *output* from a program is different from its *return code*. The return code should generally be 0, indicating success, or non zero, indicating failure. If you want the return code then you can simply run the program and check the variable `$?` afterwards:

```
./enc_ber $bytes $snr $modulation $channel $alamouti
retVal=$?
# retVal now contains the value passed back from the exit of your program.
```

Be careful not to do anything in between running your program and checking the result otherwise the value of `$?` will change again.

On the other hand, if you want your program to write a value to stdout and that's the output you need to obtain then you'll have to redirect the output to a file and then read the content of file:

```
./enc_ber $bytes $snr $modulation $channel $alamouti >./my_file.txt
output=$( cat my_file.txt )
# output now contains whatever enc_ber wrote to stdio
```

Naturally, you program will have to write **only** those things you wish to capture. Log lines and other extra formatting will cause you problems. The above is a simple example - it's up to you to parse whatever your program outputs, but the above should work for a simple number output.

Comment: i was about to upvote this but the temporary file is completely superfluous. Just `output=$(./enc_ber ...)` is the way to go, once you have fixed `enc_ber` to print, rather than `return()`, the result.

Comment: @tripleee: Yes, that's a fair point. If the output was complex and needed filtering / parsing, I'd normally write to a temporary file - deleted later - and process separately, but for a simple case, it makes perfect sense to combine the two lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store it's return value, it's stored in the special variable `?` so just

```
./cprogram
echo $?
```

that will output the exit code of `cprogram`, you could of course assign it to a variable now, if you need to call another program and retain this value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an out file,

```
gcc abc.c -o abc
```

Then you can do this,

```
output=`./abc <agr1> <agr2> <arg3>`

echo $output
```

Comment: what do you mean by `object file`? a _binary_ one?

Comment: If it take command line arguments then you should send it through same, but i don't think more than one line output can be stored like this.

Comment: object file is the compiled code file which can be run like the way i shown

Comment: Can you please show some reference where it is mentioned like you said above? I'm really interested. Also, please use `@<username>` to notify about the updates in comment. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the link. The _very first line_ of that reads like _An object file is a file containing object code, meaning relocatable format machine code that is ___usually not directly executable___ _ Please correct me.

Comment: @SouravGhosh here is more [information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718299/whats-an-object-file-in-c)

Comment: Please. stop sharing links until you _read and understand_ them. None of the two links supports your version. if `abc` is object file, `./abc` is not possible. `abc` should be an executable. If you think otherwise, enlight me please.

Comment: @SouravGhosh if this is not directly executable how can I running it?? http://prntscr.com/5sb9s2

Comment: Aghh. Who told you `-o` creates _object_ files? Heard anything called `-c` option of `gcc`? Please, do read them [type `man gcc`]. And, you're welcome. :-)

Comment: Ok thanks for all the information @SouravGhosh i will edit it to appropriate info