# My C program fails to run with `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Tags: c

I'm just starting with C. I'm trying to compile the below code and execute it, but I get an error.

Also running `size` shows nothing in BS or data stacks?

```
#include<stdio.h>
/* test.c:  My first C program on a Linux */
int main(void)
{
 printf("Hello! This is a test prgoram.\n");
 return 0;
}
```

Compiling works:

```
gcc -c test.c -o test
```

Executing:

```
bash: ./test: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Size:

```
  text     data     bss     dec     hex filename
    108       0       0     108      6c test
```

Comment: remove `-c` option.

Comment: You probably meant to use `-std=c11` or similar, to tell the compiler to compile as standard c.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok since no one <strike>wants</strike> wanted to say why... you need to remove the *-c* option **because** [according to the man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc):

> the -c option says not to run the linker. Then the output consists of object files output by the assembler.

So basically, you are not creating a *fully* executable file, [just object files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718299/whats-an-object-file-in-c).

Here's some quick info on how compiling works: http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/c/mike/misc/compiling_c.html

Answer (score 4):

The `-c` flag is not correct in this case:

`gcc test.c -o test`

-c This option is used to compile the program.

Comment: explaining this a bit further, `-c` means to produce an *object file*, not an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gcc test.c -o test` and then `./test`.

`-c` is used to compile the program (to create object file without linking)
`-o` is used to compile and link the program (to create executable) and save the resulting executable in specified output file

e.g. `gcc test.c -o test` compiles test.c and after linking creates an executable named `test` (as specified after -o flag)

Without -o flag `gcc` compiles and links to create executable called `a.out`(default)
e.g. `gcc test.c` will create `a.out` which you cam execute as `./a.out`

See `man gcc` for more details.

Comment: No, `-o` is used to tell the name of the output file. That's the problem, he told the compiler just to compile without linking and call the output `test` (instead of the customary `test.o`). Without `-c` gcc would compile and link and the `-o test` would tell the compiler to put the output in `test` instead of the customary `a.out`.

Comment: `-o` is not necessary. Without the compiler will just use a default name (e.g. `a.out` for an executable on Linux)

Comment: I already stated what was wrong. You should have read my comment carefully. Anyw2ay, here is a link to the FM: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options