# Binaries are not executing after AFL installation in qemu mode

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, libtool, american-fuzzy-lop

I have recently installed AFL and then its qemu mode, for which I required following packages.

'sudo apt-get install libtool automake bison libglib2.0-dev zlib1g-dev'

With these packages installed `qemu` installation worked fine. But after its installation whenever I tried to run binary with it, it generated `AFL FORK SERVER HANDSHAKE FAILED` error. I run my binary independently and it generated this error
`cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`. 
I searched and found out this error is because of conflicting architectures which isn't in my case as I have build and run on same machine. Compiling with libtool also hasnot been a success `libtool --mode=compile gcc -c one.c -o testlib.o`.

I am also unable to execute any binary I create as default permissions are `-rw-rw-r--`, so I have to change their mods after creating them. This was not happening before above packages and installations. I even un-installed libtool but no success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the libtool installation. I was making a silly mistake by using `gcc -c test.c -o test.o` which was not performing linking, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653556/my-c-program-fails-to-run-with-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error). All I did is use command `gcc test.c -o test.o` and everything worked fine.