# Cannot execute output files( able to execute a.out but not when I make an output file with "make")

Tags: c++, bash, makefile, output, c++14

### Question has been ***solved***, visit the bottom part of this paragraph for details.

I have a program: foo.cpp and bar.cpp and have created a Makefile to compile them.

This is how it(Makefile) looks:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c

foo.o: foo.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) foo.cpp -o foo 
    
all: foo.o bar.o 

bar.o: bar.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) bar.cpp -o bar
```

Now, when I run make all, it compiles and I have the output files there but when I run ./foo it gives me this error-->**bash: ./foo: Permission denied**

*However if I do g++ foo.cpp and then do ./a.out then it runs.*

I have seen the similar questions like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/466605/cannot-open-output-file-permission-denied and tried the solution but it did not work.

I don't understand why this is happening. Can someone please help(I am new to Makefiles)?

Thanks

## For Future visitors

**Solution and Mistakes done:**

1)using `-c flag`, it created an output file and not an executable file which I was trying to execute.

2)for more information , here is an answer on linkers: [What's an object file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718299/whats-an-object-file-in-c)

Comment: Why redefine CC to g++? you already have CXX for that. But the real problem is that your targets are wrong.

Comment: To run a file like that it needs to be marked *executable* (`chmod +x`).

Comment: @KlaasvanGend I have read that it is convention to do CC for the compiler that you are using, again I am a beginner so don't know much

Can you clarify what do you mean by targets are wrong?

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes, I have done that, it gives the following error then:
**cannot execute binary file: Exec format error**

Comment: `CC` means *C Compiler*. You need a *C++ Compiler*. See [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html).

Answer (score 1):

The file `foo` is the ***object file*** generated from `foo.cpp`. Object files can of course not be executed, since they are not complete programs.

Since you don't give a specific name for the executable, the default is `a.out` on POSIX environments (like Linux).

If you want a specific file-name then you need to add a command to create it. And make sure it doesn't clash with an existing object file.

---

I recommend you change your whole `Makefile` to something much more simple, like this:

```
all: foo

foo: foo.o bar.o
    $(CXX) foo.o bar.o -o foo
```

That's all that is needed. The object files will be created, *with the correct names*, from implicit rules.

Comment: how is foo an object file?
I wrote g++ foo.cpp -o foo and then executed ./foo(it works)

isn't makefile's work to write these instructions on the terminal?
I wrote the same instructions

Comment: @rtanmay Look at your `Makefile` again. You *don't* create an executable `foo` file, since you use the `-c` options in `CFLAGS`. Also, when running `make` it will print out all the commands exactly as it executes them, with all arguments. There you should clearly see `g++ -c foo.cpp -o foo`. Note, again, the `-c` flag.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I didn't knew about the linkers.
So, I just removed the -c flag and now it works.

But is it considered a good practice(I mean letting the compiler do the linking)?

Comment: @rtanmay So you have *two* programs? That are separate? Then they should not be linked together so disregard my `Makefile`. As for the linking, even when you do e.g. `g++ foo.cpp -o foo` you *still* link. The program `g++` is a front-end program which invokes the actual compiler and linker internally.

Comment: Thanks a lot, One more doubt, should I or should not I include -c flags in my commands.
what is considered a good practice?

I am very new to this, so excuse my ignorance
Also, I don't know why but I am not able to tag you in comments using @ sign

Comment: @rtanmay The `-c` flag is used to create object files. If you don't want object files then don't use it.