# How i extern C++ File in Assemby?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader

Im learning C++ Operating System Development.

And i have 2 file in my OS Project:
boot.asm
kernel.cpp

this is code for boot.asm

```
[bits 32] ; hey, we're in Protected Mode

[global start]
[extern _kernel] ; always add a "_" in front of a C function to call it

start:
  call _kernel
  jmp $
```

And this is for kernel.cpp

```cpp
void kernel()
{

}
```

But when i build the assembly boot file to .bin with this command:
`nasm boot.asm -f bin -o boot.bin`

so i can test with qemu,i get this error:
`boot.asm:7: error: binary output format does not support external references`
Line 7:

```
call _kernel
```

so i tried the build command to these:
`nasm -felf boot.asm -o boot.bin` or  `nasm -felf32 boot.asm -o boot.bin`

its worked,but when i execute the .bin with qemu,i get this result:
[image]

Comment: An ELF file is a relocatable [object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718299/whats-an-object-file-in-c), not a bootable binary.  You have to link it with the object file generated from the C++ source file.