# g++: Difference between "compile only" and "compile and assemble" options?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I'm just looking at the g++ help pages, it says it offers -E(preprocess only), -S(compile only) and -c(compile and assemble).

I understand the difference between preprocessing and compiling. But I've never heard assembling.
What is assembling and how does it differ from compiling?

Comment: The -S option makes the compiler emit assembly language code. The -c option makes it run the assembly language code through an assembler (at least notionally) and emit an object code file. If you don't understand the meaning of these terms, look them up.

Comment: Did you mean `-c` instead of `-C`? I edited it, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat didn't know it was case sensitive, thanks for the correction

Comment: Did you read carefully the [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) chapter?

Comment: Not yet. Thanks for the link, i'll start.

Comment: @NeilButterworth That comment helps along with answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466790/assembly-code-vs-machine-code-vs-object-code